# Do a calculation x times depending on a value

Tags: javascript, math, loops, formulas

```
Math.floor((1600 * Math.pow(1.4, 19)));  // = 956208
```

Im doing a fansite for a game and im trying to make a calculation how how much mana you need to get + skill the formula above calculates from 19-20 skill

but i need to loop the calculation x amount of times so you can calculate from x (19 in the calculation above) to y       need to raise x+1 each time until it reaches the final value y and add up the answeres from each loop like below

i have 2 text boxes that i take the values from

956208+1338692+1874168+2623836+3673371+5142719 = 15608994     so it would end up doing something like that thats from 19 to 25

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding the problem correctly (it's a bit unclear...) you want something like this.

```
var from = 19;
var to   = 25;
var totalMana = 0;

for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
  totalMana += Math.floor(1600 * Math.pow(1.4, i));
}

console.log(totalMana); // 22,808,801
```

You simply loop from your lower value, through to your upper value, evaluating your formula each time and adding it to a accumulation variable that persists through each iteration.

---

Also, just so you know, you are dipping your toe in calculus. You are getting the [summation of a finite series.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29) Math is fun, even if you dont know your doing it :)

Comment: Love is a new form of reward on Stackoverflow.

Comment: You need to make the loop `totalMana += ...` not just `=`

Comment: It happens, especially when throwing together such a fast response.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna throw this answer in for fun:

```
// generate an array with each value in the series, where callback evaluates
// the value at each step
Math.series = function(from, to, callback){
    var out = [];
    for (var i = from; i <= to; i++)
        out.push(callback.call(null, i));

    return out;
};

// add the things in an array.
Math.sum = function(arr){
    var sum = 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        sum += +arr[i];

    return sum;
};
```

With these utility functions, you can accomplish your task in a one-liner like so:

```
Math.sum(Math.series(19,25,function(i){return Math.floor(1600*Math.pow(1.4,i));}));
```